# Error: The Excel engine cannot be found

Tags: excel, sas

I am learning SAS.  I tried to run a sample program:

```
libname x "c:\Joe\SAS\class.xls";

data x.sheet2;
set x.'sheet1$'n;
bmi = 703 * weight / height**2;  
run;
libname x clear;
```

I am getting this error:

ERROR: The EXCEL engine cannot be found.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.

I found a site on the internet that said to do something like:

```
libname x excel "c:\Joe\SAS\class.xls";
```

But I get the same error.  Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably do not have SAS/ACCESS to PC FILES licensed.  Run:

```
proc setinit; run;
```

When I run that I have one line amongst others:

```
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files
        31DEC2012
```

If you don't have that line, you can't run PROC IMPORT with an EXCEL option.

There are workarounds.  For an 'xls' file, 'xls' is a legal engine, that does not require that:

```
proc import file="c:\Joe\SAS\class.xls" out=class dbms=xls replace; run;
```

I don't know if LIBNAME works as well here or not - but PROC IMPORT is fairly identical in how it works [only you have to pick which sheet up front, and do one IMPORT for each sheet].  PROC EXPORT is the output equivalent of PROC IMPORT.

Comment: ---SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files                                        31MAR2013

Comment: If you do have them licensed, then I wonder if you have a 64 bit SAS installation using 32 bit excel [or the other way around].  The bitness has to match, and I think you get that error if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

That error message typically means that you do not have the `SAS Access to PC Files` product installed.  Run this program to see what is licensed for your site:

```
proc setinint;
run;
```